# Does the converse of Abel's theorem follow from Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

$\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left(#1\right)}\newcommand{\oival}[1]{{]#1[}}\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm d}$ Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{W},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{W}),\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{W}$.

> Weaker form of the converse of Abel's Theorem:
>
> If $\seq{a_j}_{j=0}^\infty$ is a sequence of **non-negative** (Opposed to any real for Abel's Theorem) real numbers, and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j$ converges for every $x \in \oival{0, 1}$ with $\lim_{x \nearrow 1} \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j = a$, then $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j$ converges with sum $a$.

Proof: Let $\seq{x_k}_{k=0}^\infty$ be any monotonically increasing sequence in $\oival{0,1}$ converging to $1$. Define $f(j) = a_j,f_k(j) = a_j x_k^j$. Then $f_k \to f$ pointwisely with $f_k \leq f_{k+1}$ everywhere. By Monotone Convergence Theorem,
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^\infty f_k(j) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int f_k\,\dif\mu = \int f\,\dif\mu = \sum_{j=0}^\infty f(j)
$$

Does this proof hold?